# Access Webrick Rails Server from local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick, windows-firewall

Hello i am trying to access my Webrick rails server that i started on my ubuntu to my windows 7 pc locally. I checked on ifconfig in my virtual box and used the inet:10.0.2.15 when i run my rails server and also used port 80 like this:

```
rails server -b 10.0.2.15 -p 80
```

It didn't gave me an error in the terminal but when i try to go to 10.0.2.15 on my windows browser, it says it can't connect. I tried disabling the firewall in windows but still wont work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Choose another network type for your VM ubuntu. I suggest the Bridged Network. Reboot vm, it should obtain ip in same network as your windows host (example 192.168.0.XXX). Then you will be able reach your rails server from network At any port 80 or 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your ubuntu with the vm, via the apache server too? is that started?  In macs you have to enable web sharing (or something similar to that wording).  ON ubuntu what happens when you do `localhost:80`... if i recall it should say it works! or something like that.